# How Scala compiler deals with potential multiple assignments of values

Tags: scala, variable-assignment, immutability

`val`-variables in Scala should have the following properties, ensured during compilation, not later in runtime:

1. the immutable variable can not be used (a in "read") before being assigned to (bound).
2. the immutable variable can not be assigned again after being assigned once.

According to tutorials and docs it is not required to assign the `val` immediately at the declaration point as long as type is specified.

- http://www.tutorialspoint.com/scala/scala_variables.htm
- http://www.scala-lang.org/files/archive/spec/2.11/04-basic-declarations-and-definitions.html#value-declarations-and-definitions

But this seems to create a loophole

```
def fn1(x: Int, y: Int): Int = {
  val const2 : Int

  const2 = 0
  if (x < 10) const2 = x
  if (y > 10) const2 = y

  const2
}

def fn2(x: Int, y: Int): Int = {
  val const2 : Int
  var i: Int

  for( i <- x to y ){
    const2 = 0
  }

  const2
}
```

In these both examples it seems impossible to the compiler to predict whether the assignment would be singular or not. So the compiler does not have standing to prohibit this code from being compiled, but it equally does not have grounds to warrant the singular-assignment nature of `val`-variables in every execution path possible at runtime.

Whatever compiler would do, compile the code or throw an error instead, it might end on the wrong side. So what should it do, specifications-wise ?

PS. a minor question with documentation: the chapter 4.1 has says
 `PatDef       ::=  Pattern2 {‘,’ Pattern2}`
Why is it "Pattern2" repeated and having the same numeric index?
Should it perhaps be merely `Pattern {‘,’ Pattern}` instead or perhaps `Pattern1 {‘,’ Pattern2}` ?

Comment: The given examples will not compile in Scala.

Comment: Pattern2 is defined in paragraph 8.1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is illegal:

```
val const2 : Int
const2 = 0
```

`val`s cannot be reassigned after declaration, period.

Comment: If you add in class membership you can declare undefined members. But even then I don't think we can create a scenario as provided by OP.

Comment: @SarveshKumarSingh You can declare them, but you cannot reassign them after declaration.

Comment: but what would be the value of `const2` without the assignment which is done in the second line? Can you quote specs that assignment outside of the declaration is prohibited even once ?

Comment: @Arioch'The You can only have undefined declared members in a class but the thing is that the compiler will then force you to declare the class as abstract.

Comment: @SarveshKumarSingh makes sense. But this seems to be missing from official Scala specifications, isn't it ?

Comment: "Assignment outside of the declaration" isn't described in chapter 4 because, well, it isn't a declaration or a definition. It's defined in 6.15 and assignment to a value _isn't_ defined, so it isn't legal.

Comment: Guess this question is for scala development team... Does they have dedicated documentation writers maillist/forum, or do specs questions belong to general devel ?